# Genetic algorithm tournament selection, random.choice() pick same parents

Tags: python, random, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to implement a genetic algorithm, the problem is when population gets smaller, my function tournament_selection return the same parents. Here is the two main function

```
def crossover(agents, x):
offspring = []

for _ in range(len(agents)):
    p1 = tournament_selection(agents)
    p2 = tournament_selection(agents)
    split = random.randint(0, len(p2.individual) - 1)
    child1 = p1
    child1.individual = p1.individual[0:split] + p2.individual[split:len(p1.individual)]
    offspring.append(child1)
agents = offspring
return agents


def tournament_selection(population):
parents = random.choices(population, k=5)
parents = sorted(parents, key=lambda agent: agent.fitness, reverse=True)
bestparent = parents[0]
return bestparent
```

Comment: provide the first choice to the call to `p2 = tournament_selection(agents, p1)` - inside it reroll till `parents[0]` is different from `p1` ... and [edit] your code to remove the `IndentationError`s

Answer (score 3):

You could modify `tournament_selection` to return two parents:

```py
def tournament_selection(population):
    parents = random.choices(population, k=5)
    parents = sorted(parents, key=lambda agent: agent.fitness, reverse=True)
    return parents[0], parents[1]
```

Then the only other adjustment needed would be to replace your `p1 =` and `p2 =` lines by one line:

```
p1, p2 = tournament_selection(agents)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it like this

```
def tournament_selection(self, population):
        parent_population = copy.deepcopy(population)
        offspring_population = []
        for p in range(len(population)):
            parents = []
            for i in range(2):
                temp_population = []
                for j in range(Parameters.tournament_size):
                    temp_population.append(r.choice(parent_population))
                #sort solutions by fitness
                temp_population.sort(key=lambda x: x.fitness, reverse=False)
                parents.append(temp_population[0].ind.copy())
```